# open / show daterangepicker bootstrap by button or checkbox in jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, daterangepicker

How do I display / open the daterangepicker calender by checking a checkbox?
I have a checkbox "display calender". I would like to open / show the daterangepicker by checking the checkbox. It would be the same functionality that is available when you click into the input field.

```
<div class="checkbox icheckbox_flat-aero">
  <label class="icheckbox_flat-aero">
    <input id="check_tempFilter" type="checkbox" value="tempFilter" style="text-align:right;">(activate)</label>
  <div id="d22" class="col-sm-4 col-md-offset-2 input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="daterange" name="daterange" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there something like:

```
$('daterange').show();
```

I alread have bound a daterangepicker to my inputfield "daterange". The checkbox click should just open / display the already existing daterangepicker.

```
$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({

    startDate: moment().subtract('days', 6),
        endDate: moment(),

        timePicker: true,         
        timePicker24Hour: true,
        timePickerSeconds:true,
        timePickerIncrement: 1,
        showDropdowns: true,

        locale: {       
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD H:mm'               
        }
 });
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I still haven't found, what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $('#check_tempFilter').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.is(':checked')) {
      $this.daterangepicker();
    }
  });
  $('#check_tempFilter').daterangepicker();
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lq15Lo2o/)

Comment: A very good start, but I should have mentioned, that I already have a $('#daterange').daterangepicker(); That is the input field. And I want the checkbox to open the already existing daterangepicker, which is bound, to the input field!!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the focus to the input field on click of that other element. This will open the daterange picker in the right spot, e.g. i have an  calender icon behind the input field that should trigger the daterange dialog. $name stands for the name of the input field:

```
    $('#calicon_$name').on('click',function(){
        $('input[name="fpara_$name"]').focus();
    });
```